# How does Red Hat Enterprise Linux distinguish between EST and EDT

Tags: linux

We have an app that should timestamps logs with the local time, which is currently EDT. "/bin/date" clearly shows "EDT". But the app is stamping one hour in the past. I'm guessing it thinks it is EST.

/etc/sysconfig/clock contains:
ZONE="US/Eastern"

How does the above help distinguish between EST and EDT?

Comment: The daylight saving rules are part of the time zone definition. Perhaps your computer’s clock was wrong to begin with.

Comment: If you have the source code to this app, find the code where it is doing its time conversions. There may be a bug. (`grep` the source for things like `time(`, `localtime(`, and `localtime_r(`. Be careful with the open parenthesis; that's special in regexes, so you might have to escape it, depending on the RE flavor you're using.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [28.1.6. /etc/sysconfig/clock](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-clock.html)

> **`ZONE`**= — The time zone file under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` that `/etc/localtime` is a copy of. The file contains information such as:
>
> **`ZONE="America/New York"`**
>
> Note that the **`ZONE`** parameter is read by the Time and Date Properties Tool (system-config-date), and manually editing it does not change the system timezone.

The `/etc/localtime` file is more important than the `clock` file: it is a table from which the computer determines when to switch between standard and daylight savings time, as well as which timezone-offset to apply.  Note that this table can be overridden by the [`TZ` environment variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html), essentially by choosing a different table from the `tzdata` package (in case your application is for instance running as a service account with its own shell environment).

If (as suggested in a comment), your computer's *clock* is wrong, then you might consider [setting up `ntp`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html) to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

All dates in RHEL, and most other Linux distributions are stored in UTC time by default.  This includes the system clock.  This is adjusted by the time zone in the routine to read the time.

The time zone offset is adjusted by date, hence setting the time.  If the time zone is set to US/Eastern a program asks for the local time zone time it will read EDT during daylight savings time and EST during standard time.   If the program asks for the offset of the system time zone it will report the one for EDT during daylight savings time, and the one for EST during Standard time.

You must note that some applications do not use system time zone, especially web applications.  In these cases you must set the time zone in the application.  If you are having issues with timestamps of a particular application being off an hour that may just be the case.

The other possibility is that the reference clock is set to the wrong time.

Comment: The answer doesn't address OP's question.  By the way, you might want to review [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-timezone-x86.html).

Comment: It does.

The time zone information includes daylight savings time creation.

However, I will edit my answer to be more explicit about that due to your feedback, so thanks.

Comment: The answers are appreciated but not addressing the question. It seems the answer is 'It does not'.